# Formula Issue in Excel 2007

Tags: excel, formulas

I am trying to add to an existing formula. The formula will first look to see if a cell is either greater than zero or is zero, and then based on that it will select an appropriate cell.  Below is the current formula. However, I want it to look at cell `E5` first and if it is equal to zero select cell `E160`. If it is greater than zero, I want it to take the minimum value of either cell E160 or E159.

```
=(IF(ISERR(E160),E159,(IF(ISERR(E159),E160,MIN(E160,E159)))))
```

Comment: Your question says you're interested in whether a cell value equals zero, but your code uses `ISERR`. Is there a special reason why you're using `ISERR`?

Answer (score 0):

I am also confused by the `ISERR` in your formula. If you are just assessing a number, it could use the > symbol, like this:

```
=if(e5=0, E160, if(e5>0, min(e160,e159),""))
```

You'll notice also that there is a third possibility accounted for here: if the value is not 0 nor greater than 0, the formula returns an empty string - the "" at the end of the formula.